# 2D arrays in Random Forest fitting and scoring

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

I'm trying to fit a **Random Forest regression model**. This are the steps I've followed (pls see *code below* with comments):

1. Before fitting the model, I've splitted into training and test
2. I've converted the results into arrays
3. I've reshaped them to 2D arrays as the regressor likes them to be using the reshape function

I'm getting the following error (it seems that there is a 1D array even though I've reshaped them at the beginning):

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[183.  27. 520. ...  23.  28.  34.].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or 
array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Here's the code I've used:

```
#train & test split
X = order_final.loc[:, ~order_final.columns.isin(['lag','observed'])]
y = order_final['lag']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

#convert X,y train and X test into arrays
X_train = X_train.to_numpy()
y_train = y_train.to_numpy()
X_test = X_test.to_numpy()

#make them 2D-arrays
X_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train.reshape(-1,1)
X_test.reshape(-1,1)

# Fitting Random Forest Regression to the dataset
# import the regressor
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

# create regressor object
RF = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, random_state = 0)

# fit the regressor with x and y data
RF.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Prediction of test set
y_pred = RF.predict(X_test)

# View accuracy score
RF.score(y_test, y_pred)
```

And here is the shape of my arrays (which look goods to me but...):

```
print(X_train.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
print(y_pred.shape)
```

(7326, 10)
(7326,)
(1832, 10)
(1832,)
(1832,)

Can Someone pls help me out and point me where the error is? Thanks in advance!

Stefano

Comment: which line you got error?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. this is the line: ---> 30 RF.score(y_test, y_pred)

Answer (score 0):

`RF.score()` needs the inputs to be reshaped:

```
RF.score(y_test.reshape(-1,1), y_pred.reshape(-1,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the inputs used for making your predictions to the `score()` method instead, like so:

```
RF.score(X_test, y_test)
```